# График на canvas -е отражает 8 вершин вместо 7. Тоесть уходит в кординаты x:0 y:max

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

Делаю график на canvas-e. Никак не могу добиться чтобы он не начинался с x:0. В методе init задаю границы так:

```
   graphPath.lineTo(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
    graphPath.lineTo(0, measuredHeight);
```

[image: График начинаюшийся с нуля]

Эксперементами добился почти правильного результата если делаю так

```
graphPath.lineTo(6 * widthChartDivision, measuredHeight);
        graphPath.lineTo(0, measuredHeight);
```

Но он не на всю ширину.

[image: График не на всю ширину]

Вот весь код

```
`public class LineChart extends View {
    private final List<Integer> tasksPerDay = Arrays.asList(10, 7, 5, 11, 5, 4, 5);
    private int measuredHeight = 0;
    private int measuredWidth = 0;
    private Path graphPath;
    private Paint backgroundPaint;
    private Paint lineColorPaint;
    private Paint lineCirclePaint;
    private Paint lineDownPaint;
    private int dotRadius = 10;
    private HashMap<Integer,Integer> coordinateCircle;
    private HashMap<Integer,Integer> coordinateLineDown;


    public LineChart(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }
    public LineChart(Context cxt, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(cxt, attrs);

        backgroundPaint = new Paint();
        backgroundPaint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.graph_blue));


        lineColorPaint = new Paint();
        lineColorPaint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.lineColor));
        lineColorPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        lineColorPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

        lineCirclePaint = new Paint();
        lineCirclePaint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.lineCircle));
        lineCirclePaint.setStrokeWidth(10);

        lineDownPaint = new Paint();
        lineDownPaint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.lineDown));
        lineDownPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);

    }


    private void init() {
        Integer max = Collections.max(tasksPerDay);

        int heightChartDivision = measuredHeight / max;
        int widthChartDivision = measuredWidth / tasksPerDay.size();
        coordinateCircle = new HashMap<>();
        coordinateLineDown = new HashMap<>();

        graphPath = new Path();
        graphPath.reset();
        Integer coordinateStartX = 0;
        Integer coordinateStartY = measuredHeight - (tasksPerDay.get(0) * heightChartDivision);
        coordinateCircle.put(coordinateStartX, coordinateStartY);
        coordinateLineDown.put(coordinateStartX, coordinateStartY);

        graphPath.moveTo( coordinateStartX,coordinateStartY);

        for (int i = 1; i < tasksPerDay.size(); i++) {
            Integer tasksToday = tasksPerDay.get(i);
            Integer coordinateX = (i + 0) * widthChartDivision;
            Integer coordinateY = measuredHeight - (tasksToday * heightChartDivision);
            graphPath.lineTo(coordinateX, coordinateY);

            coordinateCircle.put(coordinateX, coordinateY);
            coordinateLineDown.put(coordinateX, coordinateY);
        }
       graphPath.lineTo(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
        graphPath.lineTo(0, measuredHeight);


    }

    @Override protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        measuredWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        measuredHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        init();
        setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
    }

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawPath(graphPath, backgroundPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(graphPath, lineColorPaint);
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : coordinateCircle.entrySet()) {

            float keyX = entry.getKey();
            float valueY = entry.getValue();
            canvas.drawCircle(keyX,valueY,dotRadius,lineCirclePaint);
        }

        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : coordinateLineDown.entrySet()) {

            float keyX = entry.getKey();
            float valueY = entry.getValue();
            canvas.drawLine(keyX,valueY,keyX,measuredHeight,lineDownPaint);
        }




    }
}`
```

Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь и совет!